# Python: Turn a 2D numpy array into a dictionary

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dictionary

consider I have an array like:

```
c = [["a","b","a"],[1,2,3]]
```

Now I need to combine those two parts and I want to turn this into a dictionary, which counts how often a combination occurs(the values are the number of occurances).
It should look something like this:

```
combinations = {("a",1):1, ("b",2):1, ("a",3):1)}
```

I am a total beginner and have some approaches like:

```
(c[0][0],[-1][0]),(c[0][1],[-1][1]),...
```

etc. for creating the pairs I need, but this is not very useful in case my array is of different size(both parts should stay the same size though). Plus I don't know how to put the number of occurances as values.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: `from collections import Counter; Counter(zip(*c))` ?

Comment: This seems to work fine for me! Thanks a lot! Is there a way to get rid of "Counter()" in the output?

Comment: You should read about `Counter`s, you might want to keep it like that, but you can always use `dict()` to get a regular dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `zip` to combine the 2 sublists and `count` to count specific elements in the list.

```
    >>> c = [['a','b','a','a'],[1,2,3,1]]
    >>> pairs = zip(c[0],c[1])
    >>> pairs
    [('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('a', 3), ('a', 1)]

    >>> result = {i: pairs.count(i) for i in pairs}
    >>> result
    {('a', 1): 2, ('b', 2): 1, ('a', 3): 1}
```

The last command uses [Dict Comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

Comment: After turning "pairs" into a list again it worked for me. Thank you very much!